# Update height of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a layout with ViewFlipper -> NestScrollview -> LinearLayout (parent to two RecyclerViews). Both RV have height set to wrap_content and setNestedScrollingEnable(false). Now the issue is whenever one of the RV has its adapter filtered, its still maintains it old view size even though the number of items has reduced. How can I make the RV size to adapter to new changes in the item size? I realised this started happening when I nested the two RVs in the NestedScrollView. Anyway to update the child view sizes when the content of RVs are updated. Calling notifyDataSetChanged() is't updating the view size

Comment: To have recycler view inside nested scroll view is not good idea rather try to have recycler view inside recycler view

Comment: That might work. I will look into using getItemType method to load the other recyclerView as I will just need the inner RV on the first row of the vertical RV. Maybe something like Google Play store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should Work if you put notifyDataSetChanged in your adapter every time your list is filtered. Here's an example of one of my projects where I filter a list based on a searchview Query and every time the list gets reasigned I call notifyDataSetChanged()  in the adapter

```
 @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                if (!listFiltered.isEmpty()) {
                    listItems = (ArrayList<ListaConsultaFamilia>) filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```